# I want to return a value of true or false but force it to randomly return false 3% of the time

Tags: java, design-patterns

From user input of either char a or char b as an answer.
I want to return a value of true or false from user input.
Then count the number of selections between two possibilities per individual user input.
Then force it to randomly return false 3% of the time.
The purpose is to alter the expected outcome with a reward.

How do I go about doing this?  I am new to this concept.

Comment: Use a random number between 1-100 and return false for (1,2,3) and true for the rest.

Comment: First problem: work out how to generate a random number. If you could generate a random number between 0 and 99 inclusive, do you think you could convert that to returning false 3% of the time and true otherwise?

Comment: of course depending how you get that random number into the range 0 - 99 might make it biased..... as in don't rely on the low order bits of PRNG

Comment: Reworded my question for clarity.  I am not using numbers initially only a use selection of two possibilities.

Comment: Sorry the question was not already answered but I found a solution that will work for a design pattern.

Comment: `if (Math.random() < 0.03) return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--), which gives you a random number [0,1). You want `false` 3/100 times, so if you multiply your random number by 100, your range will become [0, 100). Then just check if the random number is less than 3, if so, return false.

Comment: It's not JavaScript...

Comment: Whoops wrong link.

Comment: Now it returns a double value from 0.0 to 1.0. Your answer does not represent that anymore.

Comment: This is the basic logic for the question asked. If you want an answer that specific feel free to write one yourself.

Comment: This will work by reading the array inputs and then applying the random modification to change the inputs!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range) how to generate random num in range. You should use range [1-100]. If it gives you 1,2 or 3 return false, else true